# Can Induced electromotive force affect itself?

Tags: inductor, self-induction

At first, I want to say that I'm not English speaker, so my question might be very hard to understand. And also this question must be a silly question because I can't find any question like this...

I heard when current varies, inductor make induced electromotive force.
then it disturbs flow of current.

I have a question at this point. When it disturbs current, is this meaning that current slightly altered? I mean that the first altered current make V(=-L dI/dt), V affect dI/dt, then altered dI/dt affect to V', and V' affect to dI'... and so on?

Is (1) L related to sum of all the effect of I, I', I'', ... or (2) just first I?
Or (3) after I(=I', I'', ...) is too small, so ignore it and just calculate and get result(=inductor transient graph)?

To sum up, when I see the graph through magnifying glass, the graph will be smooth or rough(Because speed of field is c, not infinite speed)?

Thank you for reading this silly question. But this was hard to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The induced voltage across the terminals of an inductor due to a changing current flowing through that inductor is inductance multiplied by the rate of change of current.

It’s as simple as that. For instance, if the current is ramping at 1 amp per second through a 1 Henry inductor, there will be an induced voltage of 1 volt. It’s a cause and effect thing and there is no iterative formulation needed.

Comment: I meaned that is it possible: voltage induced, it changes the current, current changes  magnetic field, and then magnetic field changes voltage again and so on. like ping pong. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: I understanded your answer like this: There is no effect caused by induced voltage (no feedback effect), right? I can't accept this... Could you tell me more about this? Thanks a lot Ü

Comment: @happy1cup You could view it as having a feedback effect if you want... This is sort of where the N² term in the derivation of inductance comes from. N turns producing flux and N turns reacting to that flux.

Comment: @Felthry I found a equation about inductance of solenoid after watching your comment. It was L=uN^2A/l. N means how many winded a wire, so if wire is winded several times, flux can affects to inductor(=this case, solenoid) itself again? Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: @happy1cup Sort of! I'd have to spend more time working out exactly how true it is to say that than I'd want to, if I wanted to be completely rigorous. But it's not exactly a wrong way to think about things, at least.

Comment: @Felthry Thank a lot. I want to say more than 'thank you' but I don't know how to say that in English. :)

Comment: @happy1cup think about a plain ordinary resistor - the voltage developed across its terminals is proportional to current; well, the voltage developed across an inductor is proportional to the derivative of current. If you accept that ohm's law doesn't have a secondary effect, why should you think Faraday's law (of induction) has a secondary effect? Are you happy with ohm's law? I can't tell you "more about" something that doesn't happen other than to say it doesn't happen....

Comment: Of course, when it comes to a transformer and a secondary current flow then there are things that are more complex but that wasn't what you asked right?

Comment: @Andyaka I think there is little difference with resistor and inductor. Current flows in inductor -> current makes magnetic field -> changing magnetic field makes induced voltage... each -> is not 0 second, very short but not 0 I think. So there graph might be some ~ like shape if I enlarged current-time graph. Sorry for my bad understanding...

Comment: Like sin x = x -1/6 x^3 + 1/5! x^5 ...., I think inducter current graph might be sum of infinite series, but this is not useful to calculate, so just use derivative form for easier and faster calculation. Like we don't use x - 1/6x^3 , but use sin x. Thanks for answering this stupid question... My knowledge is like a elementary students...

Comment: Are you happy with ohm's law?

Comment: @Andyaka V=IR so voltage drop is equal to current * resistance, right? In resistor, I can accept that. But inductor makes electromagnetic wave when current varies. 'Does the e.m.wave from inducter affect something(no matter how small it is) to inductor itself?' and if it is true, 'In very short time length, dI is always larger than 0?' were my question I think. And idle inductor has no resistance, so I think there is some difference between them. Yeah, I think I have less knowledge in ohm's law then...

Comment: I think I should read and learn more.. thanks. Now this is my own understanding problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I found some picture using oscilloscope. https://dspace.org.nz/?p=605   That shaking was what I'm looking for. Is that just noise or characteristic of inductor?

Comment: It’s the effect of the self resonant frequency of the inductor under test and nothing to do with what you think. Go google self resonance and you’ll find it’s related to parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Thank you. I can do it myself now! Sorry for bothering you and Thank you for answering me. :D

Comment: @happy1cup All the feedback is already incorporated into the equation: \$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}\$

Comment: @immibis First I want to say sorry all of them answering me. I mis-asked question. V = -L dI/dt was not my question.. V is just -L dI/dt. How silly I was. I wondered inductor current-t graph. In the link I commented, there is decreasing shake. I want to explain why it happened. So I make some hypothesis. At first, dI/dt is big enough, induced V is big(-). It makes current flows slightly backward so dI<0. dI(<0) makes induced V(+) and it makes current flows forward. dI is not constant but shaking, so it converged to some value and make graph looks like V/R(1-e^-t). I wanted to know is it right.